# Why angularjs html template request does not show in browser in top sites?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I have referred following link https://wappalyzer.com/applications/angularjs to know which sites may use which programming tool to developing an application. I debug HTTP requests log in firebug and it does not show an HTML request in firebug.

There are so many sites which may use angularjs but there is one strange thing I noticed. When I show loading panel in firebug it does not load an HTML explicitly in an application means I am not able to see any HTML request in an application. While I am also developing an application in MEAN stack. It shows HTML request in firebug in browser whether I include an HTML template by ng-include or directive.

So can I know how could it possible to hide html request or is there any other way to manage templating in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Because they use angular factory `$templateCache` see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

> $templateCache is angular's build in key-value store for the template
>   contents. When fetching a template declared by a remote url through
>   ng-include or templateUrl, angular looks for it first in the
>   $templateCache and if the template is found there it doesn't perform
>   the http request.

Comment: @sahil: Thank you.. but at least first time when page loads it may seem html request log in firebug but it does not

Comment: yes first time it makes html request and then it doesn't

Comment: yes sure , I am referring it and once my issue will resolve I shall definitely give you positive wait.

Comment: you may check this post it gives a good material on $templateCache http://pracujlabs.io/2015/12/28/using-templatecache-in-angularjs.html